# Angular: How to interpolate variables imported from outside a Component?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

If a constant value is imported from outside an Angular Component, how should it be interpolated in the template?

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div>Maximum is ${MAXIMUM}</div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {

}
```

Comment: Looking for a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

no my friend you want to do something like this

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency'

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {


 constructor(public maximum:MAXIMUN) { }



}
```

now you can use the element in the .html file MyComponent.html in this way

```
<p>{{maximum}}</p>
```

i hope you get the logic inside the example if you declare x variable in your typescript file you can use it in your html file using "{{x}}"

Answer (score 1):

You should create a class variable and assign its value to the constant like this:

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency'

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent {

  Maximum = MAXIMUM;
}
```

Now use this variable in template like this:

```
 <div>Maximum is ${{Maximum}}</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

## .ts

```
1) include that external file like .js in angular.json or index.html

No need to import

declare const Maximum; //<=====
```

## .html

```
{{Maximum}}
```

## or,

## .ts

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>Maximum is {{MAXIMUM}}</div>', // No need of $
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for using template literals in your `template` is incorrect. You need to use backticks (``` `` ```) instead of single(`''`) or double quotes (`""`).

Just change your code to the following

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<div>Maximum is ${MAXIMUM}</div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})

export class MyComponent { }
```

Here is an example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-es6-template-binding).

Of course, if you are going to use `templateUrl`, then this would not be possible and you would have to assign `MAXIMUM` to a variable (say `currencyMax`) in your component so you can bind it to the HTML using angular interpolation `{{currencyMax}}` (Source: [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-and-template-expressions)). This second method would also be the standard way to go since we would prefer to use Angular's interpolation to bind our values to the template rather than template strings.

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: '<div>Maximum is {{currencyMax}}</div>',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})

export class MyComponent {
  public currencyMax: number = MAXIMUM;
}
```

Or using a separate HTML file as your template.

**my.component.html**

```
<div>Maximum is {{currencyMax}}</div>
```

**my.component.ts**

```
import { MAXIMUM } from '../utils/currency';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})

export class MyComponent {
  public currencyMax: number = MAXIMUM;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually started with ``, but someone changed it to ''... SO is getting toxic.

Comment: @user2167582 - Then what issue are you facing now? If your question is what would be the standard way to do it, you can check my updated answer :)

Comment: I'm looking for a standard way from an Angular perspective, something I hope they have some agreed upon.

Comment: So annoying having to create a local variable inside the component..